# Custom content using SudoSlider

Tags: jquery

I am using SudoSlider for my shop, and instead of an image, I want a custom content.

So I did this :

```
<div id="home-slider-menu">
    <ul>
    {foreach $slides AS $k => $slide}
        <li data-target="{$k+1}" class="custom"><a href="javascript:void(0);">{$slide.btn_name}</a></li>
    {/foreach}
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="home-slider-content">
    <ul>
    {foreach $slides AS $k => $slide}
        <li data-slide="{$k}">
            <div style="background:url('{$slide.image}');" class="slide-overlay{if !$slide.text} no-content{/if}">
                <div class="overlay">
                    {if $slide.text}<div class="text"><h2>{$slide.public_name}</h2>{$slide.text}</div>{/if}
                    {if $slide.link}<a href="{$slide.link}" title="{$slide.link_title}" class="button button-with-icon button-with-arrow">{$slide.link_title}</a>{/if}
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    {/foreach}
    </ul>
</div>
```

And my JS :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var speed = 500;
var sudoSlider = $('#home-slider-content').sudoSlider({
    speed : speed,
    prevNext : false,
    effect : 'revealRight',
    touch : true,
    auto : true,
    continuous : true,
    customLink: '.custom'
    beforeAnimation : function(t) {
        var slidemenu = $('#home-slider-menu');
        var substract = slidemenu.offset();
        var posi = slidemenu.find('ul li').eq(t-1).offset();
        var left =  posi.left - substract.left;
        var width = slidemenu.find('ul li').eq(t-1).width();
        slidemenu.find('ul li.currentone').animate({
            left: left
            }, speed).children().animate({
            width: width
            }, speed);
        oldt = t;
    },
});
```

});

When I click on the link, nothing happened, it's like Javascript was blocking it. Moreover, If I inspect the tag in my console, I can see its DOM changing, doing the animation.
So, how can I get out the system a custom link like this ?

Thank's